# How to add two or more Kendo DropDownList dynamically into a table of html5 with jQuery

Tags: kendo-dropdown

This is working for 1 kendodropdown, but I need to add 2 or more kendodropdownlist into that table, below is my code, please help me to get resolve this. I wanted to add 2 kendodropdownlist into the table, but its not adding.

Below link is working for 1 kendodropdown
[How to add Kendo DropDownList dynamically into a table of html5 with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474463/how-to-add-kendo-dropdownlist-dynamically-into-a-table-of-html5-with-jquery)

```js
 var rowCount = $('#tableImpactStmt tr').length;
            debugger;
            var contactdiv = '<tr id="idtrImpactStmtRows">' + rowCount +
                '<td id="td1" style= "padding-left: 32px!important;"><input id="ImpactStmtClientList' + rowCount + '" /></td>' +
                '<td id="td2" style= "padding-left: 32px!important;"><input id="ImpactStmtDetails' + rowCount + '" /></td>' +
                '<td id="td3" style= "padding-left: 10px!important;"><input id="idImpactStmtDeleteRow' + rowCount + '"type="image" src="/Images/red_X.svg" class="btnDelete" style="padding-top:10px;" title="Delete" alt="Submit" width="25" height="25"/></td>' +
                '</tr>';

            $('#tableImpactStmt').append(contactdiv);
            debugger;
            $("#ImpactStmtClientList" + rowCount).kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: 'ElementName',
                dataValueField: 'ElementId',
                optionLabel: { ElementName: '- - Select Client - -', ElementId: '' },
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: LoadClientNames,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: "GET"
                        }
                    },
                },
            });

            $("#ImpactStmtDetails" + rowCount).kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: 'ElementName',
                dataValueField: 'ElementId',
                optionLabel: { ElementName: '- - Select Impact Details- -', ElementId: '' },
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: LoadImpactStmtDetailsById
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: can please some one help me for this issue?

Comment: after binding the value i am getting this issue in the browser console.

"Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference"

But it was working fine when i using the statically loding from db, (control's are not generated dynamically).